# Modify Wicket FormComponent markup without panel?

Tags: wicket

In Wicket, I'd like to subclass TextField form component to add additional markup *around* the  tag.

Why I do not want to create a Panel:

1) I want the web page designer to use the input tag:
    `<input wicket:id="blah">`

2) I don't want the subclass to lose the FormField semantics in Java, e.g.:
    `field.setRequired(true);`, etc.

I'm fine with hard-coding the wrapping markup in Java.  But I'd like this to behave like a FormField in Java.

Any ideas?  Looked around for examples, but stumped on this one

Edit:
I'm aware of Borders, but my issue with them is you have to add them in both the markup and in Java.  For example:

```
<div wicket:id="border">
<input type="text" wicket:id="field"/>
</div>
```

--

```
FormComponent<Integer> field = new TextField<Integer>("field", new Model(1));
field.setRequired(true);
Border border = new MyBorder("border");
border.add(field);
form.add(border);
```

This makes the web page designer have to be aware of special markup, and the Java can't be encapsulated (as a FormField subclass).

Comment: may I ask why the designer shouldn't be aware of the special markup?

Comment: Been a while, but basically to have the designer only deal with wicket:id attributes, instead of having to worry about nesting blocks in particular ways for Wicket's sake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, this is what I wanted via IBehavior:

My wrapper behavior (sorry for the Scala syntax):

```
class FieldWrapper extends AbstractTransformerBehavior {
  def transform(component: Component, output: CharSequence): CharSequence = """
<div class="blah">
  Blah blah blah  
  %s
</div>
""".format(output)
}
```

My subclass:

```
class MyField[T](id: String, model: IModel[T]) extends TextField[T](id, model) {
  add(new FieldWrapper)
}
```

Original Markup:

```
<input type="text" wicket:id="foobar"/>
```

Generated markup:

```
<div class="blah">
  Blah blah blah  
  <input type="text" value="" name="foobar" xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org">
</div>
```

Thanks S.O. for jumpstarting my mind :-)

Comment: Yes. Behavior is what you need. Even simpler behavior with its beforeRender() and afterRender() will do what you need.

Comment: @martin-g : Wouldn't this result in duplicated (and nested) markup (before and after) when the formComponent is updated via a call to AjaxRequestTarget.add ?

Comment: @AnthonyWebster For this you may use org.apache.wicket.ajax.IAjaxRegionMarkupIdProvider. See its javadoc.

Comment: @martin-g : Brilliant! You're (as ever) a life-saver Martin!

Answer (score 2):

You wouldn't even need to subclass TextField. although it might be easier to to so if you want to reuse it. If you just want to add markup outside of the original tag, it's the poster use case for a [Border](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/border/Border.html).

Comment: Please see my edit above, I've tried Borders but do not meet my needs (assuming I'm using them correctly).

Answer (score 0):

If digging into the rendering of a Component is needed

```
MarkupContainer#onRender()
```

is your friend.

An example might be:

```
AbstractTree#onRender()
```

mf